# Interaction between quantifiers and sets in z3

Tags: z3

I am currently trying to use Z3 to encode a simple program logic for an untyped language with sets.

My symbolic execution engine needs to prove the validity of the following formula:
[image]

To this end, we ask Z3 to check the satisfiability of: 
[image]

which we then encode as the following SMT-LIB formula:

```
(define-sort Set () (Array Real Bool))

(define-fun singleton ((x Real)) Set
    (store 
       ((as const (Array Real Bool)) false)
       x
       true))

(define-fun set-union ((x Set) (y Set)) Set
    ((_ map (or (Bool Bool) Bool)) x y)) 


(declare-const head Real)
(declare-const tail Set)
(declare-const result Set)
(declare-const value Real)

(assert (forall ((x Real)) (=> (select tail x) (> x head))))
(assert (> head value))
(assert
   (forall ((result Set))
       (let ((phi1 
                (forall ((x Real)) (=> (select result x) (> x value))))
             (phi2
                (= result (union (singleton head) tail))))
          (not (and phi1 phi2)))))
(check-sat)
```

When given this formula, the solver immediately outputs **unknown**.
My guess is that the problem lies on quantifying over a variable that is bound to a set. 
To check this, I simplified the formula above, obtaining:
[image]
which we then encode as the following SMT-LIB formula:

```
(define-sort Set () (Array Real Bool))

(define-fun singleton ((x Real)) Set
   (store 
      ((as const (Array Real Bool)) false)
       x
      true))

(define-fun set-union ((x Set) (y Set)) Set
     ((_ map (or (Bool Bool) Bool)) x y)) 


(declare-const head Real)
(declare-const tail Set)
(declare-const result Set)
(declare-const value Real)

(assert (forall ((x Real))(=> (select tail x) (> x head))))
(assert (> head value))

(assert
  (not 
     (forall ((x Real)) 
        (=> (select (union (singleton head) tail) x) 
            (not (<= x value))))))

 (check-sat)
```

When given this formula, the solver immediately outputs 
**unsat**. 
This confirms my guess that the problem lies on the quantification 
over a variable that is bound to a set. 
My **question** is whether or not Z3 supports formulae that include 
quantification over sets. And, if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Quantifier reasoning is always hard for SMT solvers, and in this case you have nested quantifiers. I'm not surprised to hear Z3 simply said Unknown in the first case. Also note that you are quantifying over what's essentially a function (Sets as you implemented are really functions), which makes it even more difficult. But even if you quantified over simpler things, nested quantifiers are never going to be easy to discharge.

Did you try skolemizing your formula, putting it into prenex-normal form, and getting rid of the existentials? That might get you a bit further though you might have to come up with appropriate patterns for instantiation.

Comment: I am interested in checking the validity of the first formula (the big implication) and not its satisfiability. I don't quite see how skolemization would work in this particular case, since, after negating the first formula, the variable result is universally quantified.